# MYSQL select query using where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database, where-clause

I have the table

```
    
itemuid    |    category
-----------------------------
1          |    3
2          |    3
3          |    21
4          |    3
5          |    3
6          |    21
7          |    3
-----------------------------
```

I now want to select the `itemuid` with the `category` `21` before `itemuid` `5`.
The `itemuid` is the only information I've got from which I need to search backwards.

Can anyone tell me how the `select` and `where` query must look like? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that this example is adequately representative of the problem at hand?

Comment: Are you sure you did not mean 'before itemuid 6'? (otherwise, where would the '5' magically come from?)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table
  WHERE itemuid < 5 AND category = 21
  ORDER BY itemuid DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT itemuid from notablenameinquestion where category=21 AND itemuid < 5 order by itemuid LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT s.itemuid
    FROM (SELECT itemuid
          FROM yourTable 
          WHERE yourConditions  
          ORDER BY category DESC) s
    WHERE ROWNUM =   1
```

Comment: No need to do sub queries in MySQL, you can simply use LIMIT 1 to get the top one. Oracle background?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly:

```
Select Top(1) itemid from table_name where categoryid=21 and itemid<5
```

Answer (score -1):

If "before" means the biggest `itemuid` that is still smaller than 5, then:

```
select max(itemuid) from tablename where itemuid < 5 and category = 21
```

Answer (score -2):

If I'm understanding you correctly, this should work:

```
SELECT itemuid FROM table_name WHERE category=21 and itemuid < 5
```